# Are spaces shaped like the digits 0, 8 and 9 homeomorphic topological spaces?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Consider the topological spaces shaped like the numerals "0", "8" and "9" in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Are they homeomorphic?

I have an approach that doesnt look very rigorous to me. I wanted to know how to formalize this if its correct.

- 0 and 8 are not homeomorphic since excluding one point of 0 the space is still connected, but excluding the "tangent point" of 8, we have a disconnected space.
- Same idea for 8 and 9.
- The space 9 is union of one circle and one arc. The arc is homeomorphic to the circle, so we can view 9 as a union of two circles, then 8 and 9 are homeomorphic

PS: the topology of the spaces is induced by topology of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Comment: "The arc is homeomorphic to the circle." No, it isn't. An arc is disconnected by removing a point; a circle isn't.

Comment: @GerryMyerson yeah! My mistake. Thank you.

Comment: The strokes have width $0$ then? Otherwise $9$ and $0$ are homeomorphic.

Comment: Remove the point in $9$ where the circle meets the arc and it becomes disconnected But $8$ and $0$ are  still connected if you remove  any one point from either of them... Remove the center-point  and any  other point of $8$ and  it is still connected, but if you remove any 2 points from $0$ it is disconnected..... This $is$ a valid approach. E.g. suppose $f:8\to 0$ was a homeomorphism. Let $c$ be the center-point of $8$ and let $d$ be another point of $8$. Then the image $f(8$ \  $\{c,d\})=0$ \ $\{f(c),f(d)\}$ is connected, which is absurd.

Comment: Another approach is to look at  boundaries of members of bases for the spaces. If $B$ is a base (basis) for $8$ and $c$ is the center-point of $8$ then there exists $b\in B$ with $c\in b$, such that $\partial b$ has at least 4 members. But $0$ has a base $B^*$ such that $\partial b^*$ has exactly 2 members for each $b^*\in B^*$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, nice approach using the boundaries! I wouldnt have thought of that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

$0$ has no cut points.
$8$ has exactly one cut point.
$9$ has infinitely many cutpoints.

To show there are no homeomorphisms among $0,8,9$ use the exercise.

> **Exercise.**  Prove if $f:X\to Y$ is homeomorphism and $p$ cutpoint of $X$, then $f(p)$ is cutpoint of $Y$. Also show an arc is not homeomorphic to a circle.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the hint!

Comment: I have made an edit to your post. Feel free to revert to its original version if you disagree with my edit.

Comment: @user170039,  Pointless.